# Csv Writer - Trying to write variable in each Column

Tags: python, csv, writer

iam trying to write some data in a csv file but i cant select different columns..

```
car=["car 11"]
finish=["Landhaus , Nord"]
time=["['05:36']", "['06:06']", "['06:36']", "['07:06']", "['07:36']", "['08:06']", "['08:36']", "['09:06']", "['09:36']", "['10:06']", "['10:36']", "['11:06']", "['11:36']", "['12:06']", "['12:36']", "['13:06']", "['13:36']", "['14:06']", "['14:36']", "['15:06']", "['15:36']", "['16:06']", "['16:36']", "['17:06']", "['17:36']", "['18:06']", "['18:36']", "['19:06']", "['19:36']", "['20:06']", "['20:36']"]<br/>
myfile = open("Informationen.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(myfile,dialect='excel',delimiter=' ')
bla =[car,finish,time]
writer.writerow(bla)
```

Output:

```
car 11 Landhaus , Nord "['05:36']", "['06:06']", [..]
```

All in 1 row and Colum 1

But i want it like this

```
car 11 (in row 1 Colum 1) | "Landhaus , Nord" (in row 1 Column 2) | ['05:36'] (in Line 1 Column 3 ) | ['06:06'] (in row 1 Column 4 ) till Column n
```

Thanks for any help !

Edit
1more example how it should look like 
Line 1:  car 11 (column 1) Landhaus, Nord (column 2) ['05:36'] (column 3) ['05:36'] (column 4) [...]
example http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/4964/unbenanntvilw.png

Solution so far:
but got still problems with time list

```
car=["car 11"]
trenn=[';']
finish=['Landhaus , Nord']
time=["['05:36']", "['06:06']", "['06:36']", "['07:06']", "['07:36']", "['08:06']", "['08:36']", "['09:06']", "['09:36']", "['10:06']", "['10:36']", "['11:06']", "['11:36']", "['12:06']", "['12:36']", "['13:06']", "['13:36']", "['14:06']", "['14:36']", "['15:06']", "['15:36']", "['16:06']", "['16:36']", "['17:06']", "['17:36']", "['18:06']", "['18:36']", "['19:06']", "['19:36']", "['20:06']", "['20:36']"]
myfile = open("Informationen2.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(myfile,delimiter=' ')
bla = car + trenn + finish + trenn + time
writer.writerow(bla)
myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) states that for the `csv.writer()` function the ...

> "optional `dialect` parameter can be given which is used to define 
>   a set of parameters specific to a particular CSV dialect".

... and that ...

> "the other optional `fmtparams` keyword arguments can be given to **override individual formatting parameters in the current dialect**".

The problem you are experiencing is a consequence of writing a string representation of the `time` list to file and writing to file using a whitespace delimiter. If you were to view `Informationen.csv` as a plain text file the problem becomes apparent.

Firstly, writing to file having passed a whitespace delimiter as an argument in `csv.writer(myfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=' ')` overrides the default delimiter as defined in the Excel dialect and results in the elements of list `bla` being written to file with the format `element1 element2 element3` as opposed to `element1,element2,element3`.

Secondly, although the majority of the elements in the `time` list are allocated their own columns in a spreadsheet as desired, writing the list to file as a string representation of itself has contributed to the overall undesired formatting.

When you open the file created with your script as an Excel file, Excel reads in two initial values based on the first two commas it finds which happen to be in the center of the string `'Landhaus , Nord'` and within the string representation of the `time` list.

You can achieve the column separation you require firstly by appending the elements of the `time` list to the `bla` list, as opposed to nesting the former within the latter. You then need to omit `delimiter=' '` in `csv.writer(myfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=' ')`, thus avoiding the delimiter overriding effect when writing to file:

```
import csv

car = ['car 11']
finish = ['Landhaus , Nord']
time = ["['05:36']", "['06:06']", "['06:36']", "['07:06']", "['07:36']"]
try:
    with open('Informationen.csv', 'w') as myfile:
        writer = csv.writer(myfile, dialect='excel')
        bla = [car, finish]
        for each_time in time:
            bla.append(each_time)
        writer.writerow(bla)
except IOError as ioe:
    print('Error: ' + str(ioe))
```

producing the following output in Excel:

http://imageshack.us/a/img839/8061/screenshotkn.png

Comment: Wow - Thanks very much ! But its for me aswell not working :D but i fond a crappy way to solve it .... might be using wrong kind of csv (german version)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

car=["car 11"]
finish=['Landhaus , Nord']
time=["['05:36']", "['06:06']", "['06:36']", "['07:06']", "['07:36']", "['08:06']", "['08:36']", "['09:06']", "['09:36']", "['10:06']", "['10:36']", "['11:06']", "['11:36']", "['12:06']", "['12:36']", "['13:06']", "['13:36']", "['14:06']", "['14:36']", "['15:06']", "['15:36']", "['16:06']", "['16:36']", "['17:06']", "['17:36']", "['18:06']", "['18:36']", "['19:06']", "['19:36']", "['20:06']", "['20:36']"]
myfile = open("derp.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(myfile)
bla = car + finish + time
writer.writerow(bla)
myfile.close()
```

Here is the output I get from excel

[image]

Comment: tyvm yeap i do ... viewing it in excel....
http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/4964/unbenanntvilw.png

Comment: :) tyvm but its still in line 1 and column 1 :(

Comment: @user2195049 what line/column should it be in, in your question you say `car in Line 1 Colum 1`...

Comment: please take a look at my picture . I want each value of my variable in an own column but in same row

Comment: yeap i tried it but for me its still not working ;( ... iam using excel 2010 to view it

Comment: Thats funny :D - check this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/195/unbenanntbd.png/
but i ve got it working - only problems with time
Iam sorry i cant post code in the right way ....